# Printing in emacs "two pages side by side"

Tags: emacs, elisp

I am printing files from the terminal using:
mp -l -s "!*" <!* | lp "filename"

Which formats two side by side pages of code on one printed page.

Is there a way to integrate the exact same format to be the default when using:
postscript print buffer/region 
from inside emacs?

Answer (score 1):

See standard library `printing.el`, in particular option `pr-ps-printer-alist` and its extensive doc string.  Search for `twoup`, for example.

Comment: Drew, I think I would need to have some programs installed like gsprint/ghostprint/...etc
I work off of a server with all tools implemented by admin. I can't install any new tools.
I use : /usr/openwin/bin/mp
To print using this command:
mp -l -s "!*" <!* | lp "filename"
Is there a way to incorporate the exact same functionality without any new programs installed?

Comment: I see; yes. Take a look at `ps-print.el` in that case. See variable ` `ps-n-up-printing`. (Library `printing.el` is essentially a user-friendlier interface to library `ps-print.el`.)